# Sending email via PHP with MAMP

Tags: php, email, mamp

I have coded a contact form using php/html and all of the code is fine. I have set up multiple tests and can confirm the email is sent but still wont show up in my inbox. I have tried EVERYTHING from command lines in terminal to MAMP pro to adjusting the php.ini file and i still cant get the contents of the form emailed to my gmail account. If someone has any suggestions i would appreciate it.

-D

Comment: Have you checked all folders including spams ? And you do that locally ?

Comment: Yes i have checked all of the spam folders in my account. Yes i have been doing this locally. I am still chipping away at it but all old threads on this subject havent seemed to help. I just dont know what im missing

Comment: I use XAMPP for testing locally from time to time and have no issues with PHPMailer. I have used both my gmail account and my web address email account. The PHP Mailer set up is relatively simple in terms of email through any email server ip address provided you provide the proper info for your email provider. If you are not using PHP Mailer, I **highly** suggest giving the documentation a read and familiarizing yourself with the basics.  [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Locally, mail function will not work imho

Comment: Also, to add, there is a great debug feature in PHP Mailer, simply un-comment the error lines and set a level of error reading, the lower the more stringent the error description. Great built in tool for debugging with PHP Mailer. I use it for registration validation, network validation, cron jobs, again... very great debugging!

Comment: @Dyami Wilson also, I think it important to note that if you are using gmail, could be an issue with account access for 'less secure apps'. 

[Documentation on Less Secure Apps from GMAIL](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)
Again, I had no issue with both gmail and my domain mail servers using PHP Mailer.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think im on to something with this PHPmailer